# Infinite Motion from Finite Motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics, experimental-physics, orbital-motion

By stringing an arbitrarily large number of double-reduction gears together, it is possible to create a system (assuming no gravity and no friction) where the final gear is making an arbitrarily large number of rotations for every rotation of the first gear. This is easily demonstrated.

Therefore, conservation of energy cannot possibly be true.

Comment: Please string an infinite number of gears together and demonstrate for us :)

Comment: Using the same setup but a finite number of gears, a larger gear at the end of the chain can be shown to make more rotations than the smaller gear at the beginning. This is not supposed to be possible.

Comment: Why is this not supposed to be possible? Are you saying that gear action itself is supposed to be impossible?

Comment: As the number of double-reduction gears approaches infinity, the rotation of the final gear will make a-near infinite number of rotations for every one rotation made by the first one. This is near-infinite motion from finite motion.

Comment: Okay, and? It will also be near-infinitely hard to push. If I take one step per second due west, then as the number of steps approaches infinity then I will also have travelled infinitely far from finite steps. Is this weird?

Comment: Initial force will always be finite as long as gear string is finite. Once running, momentum of gears will do most of the "work" and one rotation of first gear will cause the final gear to perform an exponential number of rotations. Initial force can be overcome by stringing a standard gear train "backwards" in the opposite direction. Small amount of force could then create near-infinite rotations of final gear.

Answer (score 5):

> This is easily demonstrated.
>
> Therefore, conservation of energy cannot possibly be true.

The conclusion does not follow from the premise. For simplicity and concreteness, let’s consider two double-reduction gears, with the understanding that the effects can be scaled up by using more gears.

Suppose that the gears are both identical, with the small gear measuring 1 cm radius and having 64 teeth and the large gear measuring 2 cm radius and having 128 teeth. The drive gear is the first small gear, and the first large gear interfaces with the second small gear, and the end gear is the second large gear.

When the drive gear is turned 1 rotation (64 teeth) then the first large gear is also turned 1 rotation (128 teeth). When the first large gear turns 128 teeth (1 rotation) the second small gear also turns 128 teeth (2 rotations). When the second small gear turns 2 rotations (128 teeth) the second large gear also turns 2 rotations (256 teeth).

So overall, with two double-reduction gears the output spins four times as fast, as expected. Now, the speed alone does not determine mechanical power. Mechanical power is force times velocity. The velocity has quadrupled, so now let’s look at the force.

Suppose, for example, that we are driving the gears with a velocity of 1 cm/s and 100 N of force, which is 1 W power input to the first small gear. The first large gear forms a lever with the first small gear, with a 2:1 mechanical disadvantage. So the force at the first large gear is 50 N, and at 2 cm/s it also provides 1 W mechanical power output. The second small gear is traveling at the same 2 cm/s and by Newton’s 3rd law has the same 50 N force, again for 1 W of mechanical power input. The second large gear forms a lever with the second small gear, so the force at the second large gear is 25 N. This gear is traveling at 4 cm/s, so the power remains 1 W.

With 1 W input and 1 W output energy is conserved. We have changed a high-force low-speed into a low-force high-speed, but since power is the product of speed and force we have not changed the energy at any point in the process.

Answer (score 0):

At some point, things would start moving fast enough for relativistic effects to become significant, at which point the concept of rigidity breaks down. This means that some gears would start compressing, rather than exceed the speed of light.

Even if you ignore relativistic effects, accelerating the gears would require infinite torque, so it would not violate conservation of energy.

Comment: It only requires infinite torque at infinity and like you said, only during acceleration. Practical application of this would obviously be generation of electricity. Don't need anywhere near infinite number of gears. Something like 20-30 would likely work.

Comment: Also, we don't have to come anywhere near speed of light. Just fast enough to turn an armature.

Comment: And yet, there are no gear-only power plants around the world. It seems that you think that a little bit of energy into your gear-system can give lots and lots of energy out the other end. But that is just not true.